# Elements in page changes position based on screen size

Tags: html, css, position, element

The elements i placed on the header layout doesn't adjust with the screen size. The elements are flying all over the page. I want the elemets to stay in position as in the FULL SCREEN view. I'm new to CSS so i'm not sure what properties to put in to make them responsive. Thanks

**FULL SCREEN**
[image]
**ADJUSTED SCREEN**
[image]

HTML

```
<header>
 <p class=ramly>RamlY</p><image class=logo src="images/logo.png" height=100px 
 width=200px></image><p class=burger>BurgeR</p>
</header>
```

CSS

```
 header{
    background-color:#8e474c;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-width:2px;  
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#d7dbdd;
    width:100%;
    height:15%
}
 p.ramly{
    font: 400 130px/0.8 'Cookie', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:150px;
    margin-top:35;
    float:left;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-right:0px;                   
}
p.burger{
    font: 400 130px/0.8 'Cookie', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:150px;
    margin-top:35;
    float:right;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:220px;
}
.logo{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position:static
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Flexbox is likely the answer you need here.**

With Flexbox, each flexed item (`flex: 1`) will automatically expand and reduce as you scale your page size. You can also apply horizontal centering (`justify-content: center`) or vertical centering (`align-items: center`) on each item to center it within its flexed container.

```css
header {
  background-color: #8e474c;
  height: 15%;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Cookie';
}

.logo {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ramly {
  color: white;
  flex: 1;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.burger {
  color: white;
  flex: 1;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <p class=ramly>Ramly</p>
  <image class=logo src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Ramly_Burger_Logo.png"></image>
  <p class=burger>Burger</p>
</header>

<body>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel lacinia magna, vel sodales mi. Praesent dapibus felis non finibus pretium. Nam dui mauris, dictum at nibh ut, vestibulum pharetra ex. Etiam quis faucibus tortor. Pellentesque luctus elementum
  tortor, a molestie tellus luctus fermentum. Quisque vitae tortor quis urna imperdiet vehicula. Maecenas cursus lacus vestibulum metus vestibulum, et vulputate leo rutrum. Vivamus lobortis turpis id commodo lacinia. Integer quis mi risus.
</body>
```